# d3.select not updating chart in web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I want to pupdate data in a d3 chart with a click on an html object #id.

I coded it in jsfiddle and it works perfectly. However, when using it in a web page, it doesnt work. Its basically just a simple leaflet map and the chart is generated in a popup with an html `<span id=#id>` element to trigger the update.

I have no idea why it just doesn't work. I can get the update to work once by using jquery like `$("#id").click(function() {`

instead of `d3.select("#id").on("click", function() {` which is my preference.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

The working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/kaqv37gu/

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No, nothing. No errors.

Comment: Ok, try breaking within the function block of the click listener, or add a `debugger` line. Is the click just not being detected? And is the code identical?

Comment: The code is identical to the jsfiddle. I have added console.log and throw alerts to test and the click is being detected.

Comment: Right, so if the click is being detected on your webpage, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: The chart is not updating at all like in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101220/discussion-between-arcanecraeda-and-monduiz).

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue when the .onClick() was not being fired for a dropdown button. I moved the function into $(document).ready() and then it was recognised and triggered upon user action. Not sure about the reason though.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a very similar issue I'm having.